# Derived property does not get initialized from parent constructor

Tags: php, laravel, oop, laravel-5, derived-class

In my general controller GeneralController:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
class GeneralController extends Controller
{
    protected $onLine = null;

    public function __construct(Request $request)
    {
        $this->onLine = OnLine::domain($request->domain)->first();
    }
}
```

In my other controller, extends GeneralController:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\OnLine\ItemController;
class ItemController extends GeneralController
{
    public function getItem(Request $request)
    {
        dd($this->onLine); // but returns null :(
    }
}
```

I already checked, that `OnLine::domain($request->domain)->first();` returns data, which it does.

Comment: because ` OnLine::domain($request->domain)->first();` is null

Comment: In your ItemController file shouldnt the use be `use App\Http\Controllers\OnLine\GeneralController` instead of ItemController? or it is a different Class than the one you trying to extend ?

Comment: Sorry for my English(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parent constructor will help you!!

```
class ItemController extends GeneralController
{
    public function __construct()
    {
         parent::__construct();
         ....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what do you expect with `request->domain`. Is this an input or do you expect the current domain?

If this is an input, that's correct. If you want the current domain you should use `parse_url($request->url(), PHP_URL_HOST)`.

---

When you use `->first()` (or `find()`) method, if the query return 0 results, the value of 'first' will be null.

```
class GeneralController extends Controller
{
    protected $onLine;

    public function __construct(Request $request)
    {
        $this->onLine = OnLine::domain($request->domain)->first();
    }
}
```

There is nothing wrong with your code. My guess is that you forgot to send the "domain".

To make it easier to debug, just change your constructor with a hardcoded value (instead of sending a $request->domain, use any value that is already in "OnLine" table).

After that, check if you have any value from $request. `dd($request->all())`; If this is an empty array, you forgot to send the domain.

And make sure you use `use Illuminate\Http\Request;`.

Answer (score 1):

Is this a typo in your ItemController?

```
use App\Http\Controllers\OnLine\ItemController;
```

It should be GeneralController, right?